# Find normal form of a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q}^*, \cdot, 1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have troubles solving this exercise for college:

Let $G$ = {$2^h3^k$ | $h,k \in \mathbb{Z}$} be a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q}^*, \cdot, 1)$. Determine the normal form of $G$.

I tried finding an isomorphism between $G$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ $\oplus$ $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to connect it to its primary decomposition, but I had no success. What am I missing? Is this the correct way to proceed?

Sorry if I used some terms that make no sense: I am from Italy and I'm still learning specific terms for college level mathematics in English. Just ask me if you don't understand, I'll try to rewrite it the correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\left(G,\cdot\right)$ is isomorphic to $\left(\mathbb{Z},+\right)\oplus\left(\mathbb{Z},+\right)$ (torsion-free decomposition), through $2^h3^k \mapsto (h,k)$.

Answer (score 0):

No, $G$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus\mathbb{Z}_n$. (I assume that by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ you mean the cyclic group of order $p$, not the p-adics. Likewise for $\mathbb{Z}_n$.) $G$ is an infinite group; $\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus\mathbb{Z}_n$ is finite.

Ask yourself whether $G$ has any elements of finite order. Also think about a simpler case: what does the group $H=\{2^h | h\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ (under multiplication) look like?